# Use a bluetooth button in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I have a bluetooth button which normally is used to take photos with the iPhone without having the iPhone in my hands, I want to use it in my app as a button for starting and stoping a chrono. I have tried with CBCentralManager, but I only get devices like my iMac, my Apple TV or a Polar watch that I have, no sign of the bluetooth button in the list. I've also tried with the External Accesories button, and no device was listed. I've tried the EADemo sample that Apple provides and several samples, but I'm not able to connect the button to my app. I've added the Supported protocols to the Info.plist, adding the same used in the EADemo project, but without success. I've seen that the button has the MFi certificate, but how can I find the protocol that I'm supposed to add? The button is the one used in this selfiestick:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/EC-Technology-Selfie-Bluetooth-Smartphones/dp/B010UV2ENO

Has anybody faced that problem? I can see the button in the Settings bluetooth screen, it appears on the list, why I'm not able to use it in my app?

Thanks!

EDIT -- Folowing Paulw11 advice I've tried to capture the volume event, I used this code:

In the viewWillAppear I call this method:

```
- (void)useAudioButton {
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    [audioSession addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"outputVolume"
                  options:0
                  context:nil];

}
```

And I observe the property here:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"outputVolume"]) {
        NSLog(@"Button pressed");
    }
}
```

The first time it went OK, but after the first time, I've never been able to make it work again. I have the imports ok, and I don't know why the first time it worked and then nothing..

Comment: As far as I know, those buttons trigger a volume change, so you should look at the AV frameworks.

Comment: I also gone through same code, I found that observe property gets work only till increase full volume, once we reach to full volume observer will not work. 
I am also looking for same solution.